# How to convert AsyncTask for force update application to RxJava

Tags: java, android-studio, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-java2

I used AsyncTask to force update my application but it seems that doing it in RxJava is much way better than to use AsyncTask.

I tried but its not working.

Here is the AsyncTask code for version checking

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
        if (document != null) {
            Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
            for (Element ele : element) {
                if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                    Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                    for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                        newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newVersion;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {

    super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);

    if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {

        if (Float.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME) < Float.valueOf(onlineVersion)) {
            showUpdateDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

and to call this in activity i used this

```
new VersionChecker(this).execute();
```

this is what i tried but it seems something is missing because its not working

```
private void checkVersion() {
    
    Observable<String> observable = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String data = getHeadlines("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en");
            return data;
        }
    });
}

public String getHeadlines(String source) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(source)
            .timeout(30000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .get();

    if (document != null) {
        Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
        for (Element ele : element) {
            if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                    newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works!

In a new class (e.g. VersionChecker) insert this

```
public Observable<String> createObservable() {
    //Could use fromCallable
    return Observable.defer(new Callable<Observable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call() throws Exception {
            Observable<String> data = getVersion("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "&hl=en");
            return data;
        }
    });
}

public Observable<String> getVersion(String source) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(source)
            .timeout(30000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .get();

    if (document != null) {
        Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
        for (Element ele : element) {
            if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                    newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Observable.just(newVersion);
}
```

and in your activity initialize the class created for version checking and create new method to call the observable from VersionChecker class

```
private void getCurrentVersion() {
    versionChecker.createObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    Log.d("", "onSubscribe: " + d);
                }

                //on execute
                @Override
                public void onNext(String onlineVersion) {
                    if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {

                        if (Float.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME) < Float.valueOf(onlineVersion)) {
                            versionChecker.showUpdateDialog();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("", "onError: ", e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onComplete: ");
                }
            });
}
```